# Alternative to Swisscom CF plugin named Service Connector

Tags: swisscomdev

Lots of people use Swisscom developed [CF Plugin](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector/)

> After creating a service instance, you’ll eventually need to
>   administrate the service. For example you might need to create data
>   tables in a database or backup/restore your data. For these use cases,
>   we created the Cloud Foundry CLI Plugin Service Connector which is a
>   local proxy app through which you can connect to your service
>   instances using your preferred locally installed tools.

There is an alternative without installing and updating a CF plugin. CloudFoundry provide a way to `ssh` into apps, with this you can also tunnel connections to your local desktop

Comment: Please mark your question question as answered. Otherwise it always pops up as open question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Local Port Forwarding**

Local port forwarding lets you connect from your local computer to another server. To use local port forwarding, you need to know your destination server, and two port numbers (local and remote).

It's important to be in the correct Org and Space because of security groups.

```
cf t -o $YOUR_ORG -s $YOUR_SPACE
cf ssh $YOUR_APP -L 8080:opsmanager.service.consul:8080
```

now you can connect with your local browser to `opsmanager.service.consul`. Just enter in address bar `localhost:8080`. This is the [Ops Manager](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/v2.0/) offered by Swisscom with Mongo Enterprise service. It's a awesome tool to monitor and analyse your MongoDB deployment. But you can do the same trick with every internal `*.service.consul` address and port number.