# Where did the service-connector plugin go?

Tags: swisscomdev

Latest since this [checkin](https://github.com/swisscom/docs-appcloud-book/commit/d8afd73922b0a12612a96e70a3b8ac3f3b331261) the service-connector cf plugin seems to be gone for SwisscomDev.

Official [Link](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector) to the plugin simply returns a 404.

Isn't it supported anymore? What's the alternative? And did I miss communication about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't it supported anymore? What's the alternative?

Yes. Our proprietary CF CLI client plugin is phased out. The alternative is `cf ssh` (from upstream). See [Accessing Services with SSH](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html) on docs.developer.swisscom.com.

On [Migrate from legacy MariaDB to MariaDB Ent](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/migrate-mariadb-to-mariadbent.html) you have a step by step howto for `cf ssh`. Please adapt that for your service and port.

```
cf ssh proy-app -L 13000:<old-db-host>:<old-db-port>
```

Here on #swisscomdev there is also a posting [Alternative to Swisscom CF plugin named Service Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176081/alternative-to-swisscom-cf-plugin-named-service-connector) with MongoDB Ops Manager example.

We have an edge case for an enterprise customer that may still need a `cf sc` feature (not available in `cf ssh`). Investigation ongoing.

> And did I miss communication about it?

Sorry we failed in communication.
Sorry that you notice this change in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/swisscom) first. We wished to update docs first, then communicate the EOL. We somehow forgot it in [yesterdays newsletter](http://mailchi.mp/swisscomdev/swisscom-developer-portal-news-october).

Comment: So instead of a 'simple' ssh connection I need to push a separate app to connect to a service? Apps cost money, right? so whenever I want to look up logs from my ELK service I need to pay extra for a proxy-app? alternative would be local port forwarding with cf ssh? is it somehow possible to create documentation for these approaches please?

Comment: to me it doesn't sound right to use my productive app to connect to services from a remote machine for any purpose. I'll check for the example - I am more talking in general as I have to gather all this information step by step which I wouldn't expect from a payed PaaS. SwisscomDev others a couple of services - and it'd be simply great to have a doc per service how to remotely connect when necessary.

Comment: successfully used the `cf ssh` way