# where can I find the docu for the service connector?

Tags: swisscomdev

I'm not able to find the service connector documentation.
When searching for "service connector" in the documentation, I get [this link](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector) - but it points into the nirvana...
where can I find the correct documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the service-connector plugin go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606137/where-did-the-service-connector-plugin-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swisscoms' custom Cf-CLI plugin Service Connector is deprecated and should no longer be used.
Please use cf ssh instead:

https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html